.NET 6.0 and Framework Compatibility
I got a desktop app written in Visual Basic in Visual Studio using .NET Framework 4.8. This runs on a computer.
I got another app which is a C# desktop app, also developed in Visual Studio, but .NET 6.0 was used to develop this app.
I also want to run this app on the same computer. But when I tried to run the app it says "you need to install .NET 6.0 to your computer".
My concern is if I install this .NET 6.0 to this computer will .NET 6.0 somehow have any bad effects on the other Visual Basic app? Will both of these Visual Basic app (.NET 4.8 Framework) and C# app (.NET 6.0) run normally after .NET 6.0 installation?
Btw I used Devexpress components on this c# app.

Multiple versions of .NET (full/legacy) and .NET Core (.NET 6) can co-exist on the same machine with absolutely no problems at all

Ideally there should be no conflict between .NET 6 and .NET Framework 4.8, but to deploy you can create self-contained binaries for your .NET 6 application deployment on the same machine.

Mind that we are talking about the respective runtimes not the dev-kits. The runtimes will happily co-exist. That's what they are designed for.
